# Java webapp with logback and slf4j setup

Tags: logging, logback, slf4j

I am trying to setup a project using sl4j and logback.

I have some issues :

- my log file is not create.
- I my console, I have logs from external lib dispite my logger configuration

this is my current configuration :

pom.xml

```
<org.slf4j.version>1.7.21</org.slf4j.version>
    <ch.qos.logback.version>1.1.7</ch.qos.logback.version>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>logbackConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/logback.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

logback.xml (in src/main/WEB-INF folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property name="logdir" value="c:" />

<appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="STDOUT">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"
    name="FILE-TEST">

    <file>${logdir}/test.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${test}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <!-- Keep logs for 15 days -->
        <maxHistory>15</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.perso.project" level="TRACE" additivity="false"/>


<!-- External libs -->
<logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.apache.commons" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="ERROR"/>

<!-- Default og level -->
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-TEST" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

so like I said, I only have log on my tomcat console (in eclipse) and no test.log file is create.

and this is what I have on my console. I was thinking my logger configuration should avoid that:

[...]
11:43:16.982 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
11:43:16.983 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory - Looking up query for method findParametreByType
11:43:16.985 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- HQL AST ---
[...]

thanks in advance

FOr additionnal information, all hibernate and spring is contain on my com.perso.project dependency which contai log but no logback.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The issue was cause by the ${test} var which does not exist anymore. 
I also move my logback from WEB-INF dir to resource dir and it fix the issue from logging external lib.